# Is there a way to fill multiple form fields at once?

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have a form with multiple fields like this :

```
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="title45" value="title45"><input type="text" name="title45" /><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="title45" value="title45"><input type="text" name="title23" /><br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="title45" value="title45"><input type="text" name="title36" />
</form>
```

Like this, there can be up-to 100 text fields. I need a way to select several or all of them and set the value once and the selected elements will get the value. How can I do this?

I will add a checkbox infront of the fields. I want to edit only the checked ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just this line of jquery :

```
$('form input').val("fgg");
```

see this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/c53nqn7e/

Answer (score 0):

You get/set input values with `.val()`. So:

```
$('input').val('something')
```

You can narrow down the inputs selected in a variety of ways, like:

```
$('input[type="text"]').val('something') // select all text inputs
$('input[name^="title"]').val('something') // select all inputs with a name attribute that starts with title
```

Comment: How can I set the values to only the selected fields?

Comment: What do you mean by selected fields?

Comment: I will add a checkbox infront of the fields. I want to edit only the checked ones.

Comment: That's a bit more complex. It would be helpful if you updated your question to include a complete explanation of what you're after with a relevant code example.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this:

```
$( ":input" ).val("your input value"); 
or
    $( "form input" ).val("your input value");//better because it will apply only on form
```

but i'll suggest add `class` to these inputs and based on class assign the values so you can have `some discrimination`.